# Indexed properties in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

There is the _= syntax for basic properties. Which are roughly Java's equivalents for the getters and setters. But is there also something comparable to Java's indexed properties ?

I'd like to make people's life easier to allow something like this:

Setting:

```
titles.title(1) = "title of 1"  // returns nothing
```

Getting:

```
titles.title(1) // returns "title of 1"
```

Is that possible with Scala ?

UPDATE: Example code

```
class Foo {
  val title = new IndexedProperty[Int, String]
}

class IndexedProperty[A, B] {
  var map = Map.empty[A, B]

  def apply(key: A): Option[B] = map.get(key)

  def update(key: A, value: Option[B]): Unit = {
    value match {
      case Some(v) => map += (key -> v)
      case None if map.contains(key) => map -= key
      case _ =>
    }
  }
}

val foo = new Foo
foo.title(1) = Some("Title of 1")
println(a.title(1)) // yields Some("Title of 1")
println(a.title(2)) // yields None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
object titles {
  object title {
    def apply(i: Int) = "apply " + i
    def update(i:Int, s: String) = "update " + i + " = " + s
  }
}
```

Works the same way for classes as for objects.

Comment: I didn't know about the update method. Let's see if I can hack something here. Thanks !